# How to add together values from tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a webapp using Rails 3.2.8.
In this app I got three tables. Projects, Tasks and Subtasks.

**Projects**

```
id, name
```

**Tasks**

```
id, name, project_id
```

**Subtasks**

```
id, name, desc, task_id, value
```

I would like to get all subtasks that belongs to a project and sum up the values and group them by created_at.

This is what I try but it does not work (only get a AR relation back).

```
@tasks = @project.tasks.joins(:subtasks).select('sum(subtasks.value)').group('subtasks.created_at')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thankful for all help!

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I noticed the Rails version you mentioned.. A very serious exploit is available in the wild currently for versions below 3.2.11 you may want to upgrade the rails version your using now while its still in development!

Comment: Thanks, but this is ran on my local mac. I use Heroku and there I use latest version.

Comment: XSS attacks against this Rails version could compromise your Mac too! Even running this as localhost! Friendly warning! :)

Comment: Ah, wow, thanks! Honestly I did not think that but of course my mac is like any other server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're closer than you realize.

Each of the methods in the chain you have provided result in `ActiveRecord::Relation`. All you need to do is call `all` or `each` or some other method to force it to execute the query.

I think you also meant to group by `tasks.created_at`?

Finally, I'd recommend you created a class method in the `Task` model to simplify this a little.

I hope that helps.